# emotion style inner component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, emotion

I have a base Component without theme and I wish to theme it and its children, is it possible to do with Emotion?

let's I have:

BaseComponent.jsx

```
const Wrapper = styled('div')``;
const Inner1 = styled('div')``;
const Inner2 = styled('div')``;

export MyBaseComponent = () => (
  <Wrapper>
    <Inner1 />
    <Inner2 />
  </Wrapper>
);
```

ThemedMyComponent.jsx

```
export ThemeMyComponent = () => {
   ???
  return (
    <MyBaseComponent ??? ??? ??? />
  )
}
```

all my theme stuff are in the second component and I would like to complex logic and decorate the `BaseComponent` only inside `ThemedMyComponent`.

initial approach would be:

```
const Wrapper = styled('div')``;
const Inner1 = styled('div')``;
const Inner2 = styled('div')``;

export MyBaseComponent = (props) => (
  <Wrapper className={props.wrapperClassName}>
    <Inner1 className={props.inner1ClassName}/>
    <Inner2 className={props.inner2ClassName}/>
  </Wrapper>
);
```

and pass 3 className to it, which means I have to use `withTheme` and do a lot of `cx`, and not mentioning, you can't not longer do this with emotion 10. is there a more functional way to do this?

Doing this, the whole thing I would need is just `css` from the `ClassNames` render callback, which make `styled` unused...